# Express request.cookies is seting the cookies with %

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to set this dictionary:
`dados: { email: 'danielfernandolucianodavid48@gmail.com', iduser: 3, nome: 'Daniel David', nomecategoria: 'Protetor' }` in a cookie using request.session.

My code that is trying set is as it:

```
response.cookie('lgadasdadfdvqwdsfgweklfcwevw_wdwcbwecwv_Wdwd', JSON.stringify(dados).replace(":", "=").replace(/\{|\}|\"/g, "").replace(",", ";"), { maxAge: 900000, httpOnly: false });
```

But when I will see the cookie, it is as it:

```
email%3Ddanielfernandolucianodavid48%40gmail.com%3Biduser%3A3%2Cnome%3ADaniel%20David%2Cnomecategoria%3AProtetor
```

[Print of the cookie seted in Chrome browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcPu5.png)

Comment: Cookies are URL-encoded because they can't contain some special characters.

Comment: It encodes `=` as `%3d` which is `=` in ascii

Comment: Do u know how can I modify this encode? Because I've been seeing that appears not possible replace all ascii characters correctly

Comment: @DanielDavid you can use `JSON.parse()` when retrieving the cookie, and it will decode it for you